# Placing a text cursor anywhere on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, text

Let's say I dynamically draw rectangles on a canvas in my app when user clicks somewhere on it. Then I want to let him add some text to these rectangles so that he can click on some of the existing rectangles and start typing into them, adding new text or changing text which is already in them. So a nice solution would be something like placing the text cursor anywhere on the canvas or something similar which would allow the user start typing anywhere on the canvas. The alternative solution which I use now is that the user types some text in an input element and then I draw the text from input into the rectangle with `fillText()` method. Is there a way to do it the way I want?

Comment: The canvas is a container that holds pixels, it does not understand what those pixels represent. Any higher level abstract properties you want to assign to the canvas must be managed by you. So to answer your question. Yes there is a way, listen to the keyboard events and create the functionality of a text input in javascript

Comment: Ditto what @Blindman67 says, plus ... you can strip the style off an input-type-text and temporarily z-index it over the canvas when the user triggers their first keyboard event. Without styling, the input control becomes "transparent" except for the typed text. That way you have the full editing capability of the input control on the canvas. ;-)

Comment: Thanks guys, I used keyboard events in javascript and everytime a key is pressed I rewrite the text in the object.